# Do the Tinkers ever find their song?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

This involves Memory of Light

> I just finished the last book in WoT and I don't recall a moment where the Tinkers find the song that they are searching for.  I recall that the Ogier sing at one point but that is about it.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, the Tinkers will not find their song.

> **Brandon Sanderson:**
>  Robert Jordan's notes on this are very clear: the Tinkers will never find their song. They've lost it for too
>   long, that even if someone stood in front of them singing The Song,
>   they would just nod their head, say 'that's a nice song' and go on
>   their way.

From an [Interview transcript](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=872#1) on Theoryland

The Song itself is the growing song Rand heard in Rhuidean.

> **Robert Jordan:**
>  The Song the Tinkers are seeking is the song Rand heard in Rhuidean—or, to be exact, the memories of that song and
>   others like it have become merged, over the years, into the concept of
>   one mystical Song.

From another [Interview transcript](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=648#1) on Theoryland.

Comment: Note that, when Rand confronts Tuon for the second time, Mat catches him humming something under his breath as the nearby plants explode into bloom. I strongly suspect that is supposed to be the growing song.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Yep, that's confirmed by BS on the link to the first interview.

Comment: Great, now I'm going to have dreams where the Entwives march by, singing the Tinker's Song while carrying Bigfoot & Elvis.